# English equivalent for Spanish "atrilista" (orchestra musician)

Tags: single-word-requests

In Spanish "**atrilista**" is an special orchestra musician. What is the equivalent in English language?

> El músico *atrilista* solo toca lo que viene escrito en la partitura, el
>   intérprete toma este nombre porque es capaz de dar su interpretación
>   personal de una pieza.

Since I am very aware that there are strict rules for single-word-requests, to ensure my question is not closed as off-topic, I do hereby provide below a specific about the intended use of the word. I am including a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used:

> The *atrilista* musician only plays what is written in the score, conversely, the *interpreter* takes this name because it is capable of giving their personal interpretation of a piece.

Comment: Can you expand on this meaning a bit please?  Eg is there a "non-special" orchestra musician, and if so what's the difference?  Do you change from a non-atrilista to an atrilista at the moment you get a job with the orchestra, or is it more of a slow process?

Comment: Please provide an *English* description of your Spanish term.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used."  You can add these details by clicking on the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: Probably the term you want is "musician with an/the orchestra".

Comment: @HotLicks The MET in NYC just calls them orchestra musicians
[metorchestramusicians.org](http://www.metorchestramusicians.org/the-musicians/)
Here we must admit that there are othes, not only Orchestra but also Symphony, and Philharmonic musicians.

Comment: @MaxWilliams You made a good point.

Comment: @Lawrence I do not have one, that is why I need help. Had I had an English definition/description, translating would probably be easier.
From latin _atrium_, an _Atril_ is actually a _Lectern_, a lectern utilized to hold a partiture. Hence, the _Atrilista_ plays only what is written in the partiture.

Comment: @gral.pancho.villa The problem is that you've provided a term *and* its definition in a foreign language (*foreign* relative to English, that is), neither of which is comprehensible to those who don't understand the other language. So you can see where I'm coming from, consider a term *blah* whose definition is *blaa blab blac* in some foreign language. How do you determine what *blah* means when you understand neither *blah* nor *blaa blab blac*? A translation of (most of) the words in your Spanish definition would help.

Comment: @Lawrence There you go: The _atrilista_ musician plays only what is written in the partiture, conversely the _interpreter_ takes this name because it is capable of giving their personal interpretation of a piece.

Comment: @gral.pancho.villa Thanks, that's much clearer. I see that Andrew Leach has answered the question along these lines, so I'll bow out from this discussion. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Translate's translation of the Spanish is

> The *atrilista* musician plays only what is written in the score, the *intérpete* takes this name because it is able to give his personal interpretation of a piece.

Based on this, I don't think that *atrilista* is a special member at all: he's distinctly ordinary and would probably be a **rank-and-file** member of the orchestra — a player in the middle of the string section, for example.

An *intérpete* might be someone who can create a cadenza — he is a **soloist.**

However, as Max Williams has pointed out, it may be that the "personal interpretation" isn't a solo but rather extra expression, to bring the piece "to life" more effectively. To be a more expressive player, in other words.

If this is the case, then the *atrilista* could be described as a **jobbing member** of the orchestra. While this often means a [casual](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/job?q=jobbing#job__15) (non-permanent) member, it can imply a more casual attitude, simply turning up and playing what's in front of him. Such a player will be a rank-and-file player in an orchestra.

Comment: This sounds plausible, but it may be that the "personal interpetation" isn't a solo but rather extra expression, to bring the piece "to life" more effectively.  To be a more expressive player, in other words.

Comment: @Max Hm. You're right. I'll update the answer...

Comment: @AndrewLeach So, apparently there is an interpretation, even though there is no one-to-one translation for this word.
In the end I believe that translating Atrilista as ORCHESTRAL MUSICIAN is a good approach.

Comment: From latin _atrium_, an _Atril_ is actually a _Lectern_, a lectern utilized to hold a partiture or music sheet.
Anyhow, at this point _lecternist musician_ does not seems appealing.

Comment: We call such a lectern a *music stand.* And it's sounding more and more that ***rank-and-file*** is the adjective to use.

Answer (score 1):

> The *atrilista* musician only plays what is written in the score.

The ***section player*** [or the ***section musician***] only plays the notes on the page.

This is to distinguish from the soloist, or first chair musicians (or first stand musicians).

The *section player* is somewhere in the middle of the section.

(There's a third type, the back-of-the-section musician, who's only in the job for the paycheck.)

You could also say, "Ignacio is a notes-on-the-page kind of guy.  Don't ask him to be creative."